# i want to active different div if crawler condition is satisfied

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

This is the div which contain the character and is active when we click on the character a j query function is executed and it shows the other countries

//this is the div i want to keep active when crawler condition is fulfilled.It contains the starting character of the countries

```
<div class="serving-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <span>COUNTRIES:</span>
    <%-- <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-alpha="Popular Destinations" class="active">Popular Destinations</a>--%>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-alpha="A">A</a>// this character should be active when crawler condition is satisfied.
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-alpha="B">B</a>
  </div>
</div>
// whenever the crawler condition is Satisfied then it shows show the country of 
//all the characters.
```

This below is the div which shows the popular country and it is shown default

```
<div class="serving-nav-data" style="display: block;" data-alpha="Popular Destinations">
  <h5>Popular Destinations</h5>

  <div class="serving-boxes">
    <div class="row">
      <% foreach (var p in popularRegionRates) {%>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="serving-box">
            <div class="the-flag">
              <img src="/Content/images/AboutUs/country-flags/<%=p.CountryName %>.png" alt="<%=p.CountryName  %> Courier" class="img-tall">
            </div>

            <% string modName="" ; //modName=p .CountryName.Replace( " AND ", " & "); modName=p .CountryName; if (modName.IndexOf( "(") !=- 1 && modName.Length>15) { modName = p.CountryName.Substring(0, p.CountryName.IndexOf('(')); %>
              <h3 itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="" class="destiText" title="<%=%> Delivery from £<%=%>"><%=%> Delivery from <span itemprop="lowPrice">£<%=%></span></h3> 
              <%} else { if (modName.Length>18) {%>
                <h3 itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="" class="destiText" title="<%=%> Delivery from £<%=p%>"><%=modName%> from <span itemprop="">£<%=p%></span></h3>
                <%} else {%>

                  <h3 itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="" class="destiText" title="<%=%> Delivery from £<%=p%>"><%=%> Delivery from <span itemprop="">£<%=p%></span></h3> 
                  <%} %>
                    <%}%>


                      <% if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.PageName)) {%>
                        <a class="book-btn trans-ease" title="to <%=p.CountryName %>" href="">Get Price &amp; Book</a>
                        <%} else{ %>
                          <a class="book-btn trans-ease" title="to <%=p.CountryName %>" href="<%=p.PageName %>">Get Price &amp; Book</a>
                          <%} %>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <%} %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This below is the condition that i want to implement for the crawler

```
//Check userAgent to serve organic number to Googlebots
        var gb = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('googlebot');

        //Check userAgent to serve organic number to Bingbots
        var bb = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('bingbot');

        //Check userAgent to serve organic number to MSNbots
        var mb = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msnbot');

        //For Blocking Animation through QueryString
        var qrStr = window.location.toString();

        if (((gb > 0) || (bb > 0) || (mb > 0)) || (qrStr.indexOf('animation=false') > 0))
         {

        }
```

These above the conditions of the crawler that have to be implemented and i don't want to show the popular destinations div by default in case of crawler .It should show all the character at page by default.

I am using a j query function on the click of the character that is defined below

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        //  Listen for Click
        $(".serving-nav a").click(function (e) {

            //  Get the Character
            var theChar = $(this).data('alpha');

            //  Hide Others
            $(this).parent().find('a').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
          $(".serving-data .serving-nav-data").stop(true, true).slideUp(500);

            // $(".serving-data .serving-nav-data").show();

            //  Show the Related
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(".serving-data .serving-nav-data[data-alpha='" + theChar + "']").stop(true, true).slideDown(500);

            //  Prevent Default
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

        //  Trigger Click on Active One
        $(".serving-nav a.active").click();
    });
```

Comment: Can you please define what you want to achieve more clearly?

Comment: see as defined above there are two different divs and i want to write that crawler conditions on the page and if the crawler conditions are satisfied then it should show the first div and if the conditions are not satisfied then it should show the default div that is the second div.

Answer (score 0):

You just can play with `.show(); and .hide();` 
By default .hide() the divs and then if condition is true .show() the necessary div.